# How to add Azure App Service Wildcard Custom Domian

Tags: azure, wildcard, custom-domain

I cannot seem to add a wildcard domain to an Azure App Service. I know I have done this in the past but I think the portal has changed.

There are several examples online of how to do this but all of them state you can enter a domain as "*.mydomain.com" which does not work thru the Azure portal.

I go into the my app's App Service page-->Custom Domains-->Add Custom domain. I select "All other domain services" and the Domain field appears. I want to enter *.mydomain.com but the portal will not allow an *.

How do you add a wildcard custom domain. I will have hundreds of subdomains in a multi-tenant app. I already have the wildcard cert and the CNAME and TXT records setup.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a **`Wildcard Domain`** refer the steps from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=wildcard,azurecli).

***Visit your Azure Web app > Custom Domains > For Wildcard domain to get accepted, Select Add certificate later option in TLS/SSL certificate > In domain add your wildcard domain like here:- **`*.contoso.com`*****

[image]

Now visit your Domain registrar site and in the DNS records Add the below records for the Wildcard domain to work properly:-

[image]

In your **`DNS Record`** add the above **`CNAME`** and **`TXT records`**:-

```
Type- CNAME , 
Name- * ,
Data- webappname.azurewebsites.net,

Type- TXT, 
Name- asuid, 
Value - A189264E6xxxxx833044629E67A8D1AC75146808B3
```

Reference [**MS Document.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=wildcard,azurecli#2-create-the-dns-records)

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! The trick was selecting "Add Certificate Later". Once you select that you can add the *.mydomain.com. Much appreciated.